# I am unable to login to heroku via the web, what to do?

Tags: heroku

I can not connect to my account. 
I tried to reset my password but i do not receive the confirmation email.
What to do?

Comment: Wait a few minutes for the email to arrive. Check your spam folders. Make sure you're providing the email address you actually used to sign up.

Comment: If the email isn't in your spam folder I would also suggest reaching out to heroku support. It's possible their email system isn't able to deliver the reset email for some reason.